# How to get order Id in conformation mail in opencart

Tags: php

I am currently working in open-cart E shop.In that open cart,I received conformation mail with product details. In order id doesn`t received through mail user without login. when user will login then only, order id will display correctly..I am facing this error..

```
Notice: Undefined variable: order_id in /home/demoosiz/public_html/cart/OpenCart/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-catalog_controller_account_order.php on line 156Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/demoosiz/public_html/cart/OpenCart/index.php:104) in /home/demoosiz/public_html/cart/OpenCart/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-system_engine_controller.php on line 28Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/demoosiz/public_html/cart/OpenCart/index.php:104) in /home/demoosiz/public_html/cart/OpenCart/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-system_engine_controller.php on line 29
```

Let me know how to solve it. please Provide solutions for this....

Comment: That means $order_id is not intialized.Try initializing it before using the variable

Comment: Thank you @Deepu..even though i give isset($order_id) function in that order_id=xx when it show only after login, before login it will not shown otherwise it will not redirect into login page...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) to check whther the variable is set or not like this

```
if(isset($order_id)){
//Do something
}
else{
//do something
}
```

Comment: Hi @Deepu....I will set Isset before order_id..It will not shown any more error, but its will redirect into login page further login it doesn`t redirect into order page which contain order_id(Order_id=)is empty.How to solve it..please guide for this..am struggling for this...I need ur comments..